Local and Global costmaps not showing up in rviz
I have been working on an autonomous navigation for a 3wheeled robot. I am using hector-slam for mapping (and already have several maps saved) and want to use move_base for the navigation. My main problem is that 2 days ago it was working perfectly as I intended, than after a restart of the robot it stopped working. Initially it was showing me only a blob as a global costmap and the same thing as the local costmap. I tried playing around with the parameters and plugins but now I set everything back to how it was when it was working properly, and now the local costmap won't even load and the global costmap is just and empty square.
Please if anyone has encountered this and has an idea of how I could solve it let me know.
Here are my .yaml and .launch files:
base_local_planner_params.yaml:
TrajectoryPlannerROS:
  max_vel_x: 1.4
  min_vel_x: 0.028
  max_vel_theta: 0.7
  min_in_place_vel_theta: 0.3

  acc_lim_x: 0.8
  acc_lim_theta: 2.0

  holonomic_robot: false

  xy_goal_tolerance: 0.2
  yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.1

  sim_time: 1.5
  sim_granularity: 0.025
  angular_sim_granularity: 0.02

  meter_scoring: true

  escape_vel: -0.1
  oscillation_timeout: 10
  oscillation_distance: 0.2

costmap_common_params.yaml:
obstacle_range: 2.5
raytrace_range: 3.0
footprint: [[1.16,0.39], [-0.60,0.39], [-0.60,-0.39], [1.16,-0.39]]
inflation_radius: 0.5

observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor
laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: laser3d, data_type: LaserScan, topic: /scan, marking: true, clearing: true}

inflation:
  inflation_radius: 1.0

static:
  map_topic: /map
  subscribe_to_updates: false

global_costmap_params.yaml:
global_costmap:
  global_frame: map
  robot_base_frame: base_link
  update_frequency: 1.0
  publish_frequency: 1.0
  width: 30.0
  height: 30.0
  resolution: 0.05
  transform_tolerance: 0.5
  static_map: true

  plugins:
    - {name: static, type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
    - {name: obstacles_laser, type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"}
    - {name: inflation, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}

Local_costmap_params.yaml:
local_costmap:
  global_frame: odom
  robot_base_frame: base_link
  update_frequency: 5.0
  publish_frequency: 2.0
  static_map: false
  rolling_window: true
  width: 3.0
  height: 3.0
  resolution: 0.1
  transform_tolerance: 0.5

  plugins:
    - {name: obstacles_laser, type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"}
    - {name: inflation, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}

My launch file:
<launch>
    <!-- Run Map Server -->
    <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(find innok_heros_slam_navi)/maps/flex_big_200524.yaml" respawn="false">
        <param name="frame_id" value="map" />
    </node>

    <!-- Run AMCL -->
    <node pkg="amcl" type="amcl" name="amcl" output="screen">
        <param name="initial_pose_x" value="0.0"/>
        <param name="initial_pose_y" value="0.0"/>
        <param name="initial_pose_a" value="0.0"/>
    </node>

    <!-- Run move_base -->
    <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
        <rosparam file="$(find innok_move_base)/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find innok_move_base)/Local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
        <rosparam file="$(find innok_move_base)/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find innok_move_base)/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
        <rosparam file="$(find innok_move_base)/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load"/>
    </node>

    <!-- Set robot_description parameter -->
    <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro '$(find innok_heros_description)/urdf/innok_heros_3wtractor.xacro' front_kind:=front_caster wheel_kind:=wheel" />

    <!-- Ensure TF Tree -->
    <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" name="robot_state_publisher" />

    <!-- Static transforms -->
    <!-- Ensure no redundant static transforms are present to avoid loops -->
    <!-- <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="static_transform_odom_map" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /odom /map 100" /> -->
    <!-- <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="static_transform_base_odom" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /base_link /odom 100" /> -->

    <!-- Launch RViz for visualization -->
    <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(find innok_move_base)/rviz/navigation.rviz"/>
</launch>

And the oputput on the terminal after starting my launch file:
PARAMETERS
 * /amcl/initial_pose_a: 0.0
 * /amcl/initial_pose_x: 0.0
 * /amcl/initial_pose_y: 0.0
 * /map_server/frame_id: map
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/acc_lim_theta: 2.0
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/acc_lim_x: 0.8
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/angular_sim_granularity: 0.02
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/escape_vel: -0.1
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/holonomic_robot: False
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/max_vel_theta: 0.7
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/max_vel_x: 1.4
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/meter_scoring: True
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/min_in_place_vel_theta: 0.3
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/min_vel_x: 0.028
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/oscillation_distance: 0.2
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/oscillation_timeout: 10
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/sim_granularity: 0.025
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/sim_time: 1.5
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/xy_goal_tolerance: 0.2
 * /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.1
 * /move_base/global_costmap/footprint: [[1.16, 0.39], [-...
 * /move_base/global_costmap/global_costmap/global_frame: map
 * /move_base/global_costmap/global_costmap/height: 30.0
 * /move_base/global_costmap/global_costmap/plugins: [{'name': 'static...
 * /move_base/global_costmap/global_costmap/publish_frequency: 1.0
 * /move_base/global_costmap/global_costmap/resolution: 0.05
 * /move_base/global_costmap/global_costmap/robot_base_frame: base_link
 * /move_base/global_costmap/global_costmap/static_map: True
 * /move_base/global_costmap/global_costmap/transform_tolerance: 0.5
 * /move_base/global_costmap/global_costmap/update_frequency: 1.0
 * /move_base/global_costmap/global_costmap/width: 30.0
 * /move_base/global_costmap/inflation/inflation_radius: 1.0
 * /move_base/global_costmap/inflation_radius: 0.5
 * /move_base/global_costmap/laser_scan_sensor/clearing: True
 * /move_base/global_costmap/laser_scan_sensor/data_type: LaserScan
 * /move_base/global_costmap/laser_scan_sensor/marking: True
 * /move_base/global_costmap/laser_scan_sensor/sensor_frame: laser3d
 * /move_base/global_costmap/laser_scan_sensor/topic: /scan
 * /move_base/global_costmap/observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor
 * /move_base/global_costmap/obstacle_range: 2.5
 * /move_base/global_costmap/raytrace_range: 3.0
 * /move_base/global_costmap/static/map_topic: /map
 * /move_base/global_costmap/static/subscribe_to_updates: False
 * /move_base/local_costmap/footprint: [[1.16, 0.39], [-...
 * /move_base/local_costmap/inflation/inflation_radius: 1.0
 * /move_base/local_costmap/inflation_radius: 0.5
 * /move_base/local_costmap/laser_scan_sensor/clearing: True
 * /move_base/local_costmap/laser_scan_sensor/data_type: LaserScan
 * /move_base/local_costmap/laser_scan_sensor/marking: True
 * /move_base/local_costmap/laser_scan_sensor/sensor_frame: laser3d
 * /move_base/local_costmap/laser_scan_sensor/topic: /scan
 * /move_base/local_costmap/local_costmap/global_frame: odom
 * /move_base/local_costmap/local_costmap/height: 3.0
 * /move_base/local_costmap/local_costmap/plugins: [{'name': 'obstac...
 * /move_base/local_costmap/local_costmap/publish_frequency: 2.0
 * /move_base/local_costmap/local_costmap/resolution: 0.1
 * /move_base/local_costmap/local_costmap/robot_base_frame: base_link
 * /move_base/local_costmap/local_costmap/rolling_window: True
 * /move_base/local_costmap/local_costmap/static_map: False
 * /move_base/local_costmap/local_costmap/transform_tolerance: 0.5
 * /move_base/local_costmap/local_costmap/update_frequency: 5.0
 * /move_base/local_costmap/local_costmap/width: 3.0
 * /move_base/local_costmap/observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor
 * /move_base/local_costmap/obstacle_range: 2.5
 * /move_base/local_costmap/raytrace_range: 3.0
 * /move_base/local_costmap/static/map_topic: /map
 * /move_base/local_costmap/static/subscribe_to_updates: False
 * /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /rosdistro: noetic
 * /rosversion: 1.16.0

NODES
  /
    amcl (amcl/amcl)
    map_server (map_server/map_server)
    move_base (move_base/move_base)
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher)
    rviz (rviz/rviz)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

process[map_server-1]: started with pid [34952]
process[amcl-2]: started with pid [34953]
process[move_base-3]: started with pid [34954]
process[robot_state_publisher-4]: started with pid [34964]
process[rviz-5]: started with pid [34971]
[ INFO] [1716388406.440303110]: Subscribed to map topic.
[ INFO] [1716388406.606995827]: Received a 4096 X 4096 map @ 0.050 m/pix

[ INFO] [1716388407.033325050]: Initializing likelihood field model; this can take some time on large maps...
[ INFO] [1716388407.440626963]: Done initializing likelihood field model.
[ INFO] [1716388407.466249985]: global_costmap: Using plugin "obstacle_layer"
[ INFO] [1716388407.476596391]:     Subscribed to Topics: laser_scan_sensor
[ INFO] [1716388407.495084421]: global_costmap: Using plugin "inflation_layer"
[ INFO] [1716388407.538385276]: local_costmap: Using plugin "obstacles_laser"
[ INFO] [1716388407.544317856]:     Subscribed to Topics: 
[ INFO] [1716388407.551109570]: local_costmap: Using plugin "virtual_walls_static_map"
[ INFO] [1716388407.558423220]: Requesting the map...

If any additional info would be needed please let me know.
